# (Tcl/Tk) Creating a persistent options window?

Tags: user-interface, dialog, tcl, tk-toolkit

Stackoverflow!

My issue here is two-part; the first part is I have no idea what this concept is actually called which is why I had an incredibly difficult time searching for it anywhere! Part two is I'm not sure how it would be implemented in Tcl/Tk. Here goes...

So how would one make one of those persistent "settings" toplevels where you have to finish what you're doing in that window either by clicking "cancel" or "ok" before you can return to the main GUI? I understand I can give a window the `topmost` attribute with the `wm attributes` which will keep the window on top of ever other window, but that's not quite what I want.

Comment: The phrase you're looking for is “modal dialog”.

Comment: Ah YES! That's it! Thank you. Sorry for the silly question, It's been bothering me literally all day. I have to make a modal dialogue and I don't even know it's called that T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a modal dialog in Tk, you need to set a `grab` so that mouse events are directed to the dialog window. You probably also need to make sure that the `focus` is somewhere in the dialog. (Don't use a global grab — `grab -global` — unless you know what you're doing and are very careful; you can lock your whole GUI from user interaction with that. You *should not* use global grabs for modal dialogs.)

Grabs can only be set on mapped windows. On Unix, the `tkwait visible` command is perfect for making things pause momentarily until the window is actually mapped. On Windows and OSX, it doesn't really work though an appropriate `after` can help a lot, as can watching for the first time an `<Expose>` event is processed (which is what an *actual* draw of the dialog is postponed to).

You might also want to look at using `tkwait variable` (a.k.a., `vwait`) so that you can use the dialog in a blocking fashion from within your code; you just set the (global!) variable from the `OK` and `Cancel` buttons. It's not necessary, but it's a reasonably common pattern. If you do that, make sure that if the user just closes the dialog by clicking on its `X` window decoration, you still terminate the wait. The `<Destroy>` event is useful for that (though be careful with trapping a `<Destroy>` on any toplevel; it also detects destruction of child widgets).

Finally, a reasonable place to start looking at how to do this is Tk's own [`tk_dialog`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/dialog.htm) command. It's just a procedure, so you can read the source easily. Or you can look [online](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/artifact/31deb1e48cb3cac6?ln) (particularly check from line 148 onwards). The procedures it calls are all in [tk.tcl](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/artifact/f926123d8759aa19?ln)…